# Component not loading in Angular 2 app AoT compilation

Tags: javascript, angular, aot, rollupjs

I followed the steps on the website 'https://angular.io/guide/aot-compiler' to adapt an Angular 2 app to use AoT compilation and everything seemed to work as expected until the rollup step, which in theory cleans up the code of unused components.

Leaving the 'rollup-config.js' file the same as in the instructions, when I run 'node_modules/.bin/rollup -c rollup-config.js' I get the following error:

> [!] Error: 'ToastModule' is not exported by node_modules/ng2-toastr/ng2-toastr.js

I've googled it, and I came across a solution that pointed to add a 'namedExports' field to the 'commonjs' parameter. The resulting 'rollup-config.js' is:

```
import nodeResolve from 'rollup-plugin-node-resolve';
import commonjs from 'rollup-plugin-commonjs';
import uglify from 'rollup-plugin-uglify';

export default {
    entry: 'src/main.js',
    dest: 'src/build.js',
    sourceMap: false,
    format: 'iife',
    onwarn: function(warning) {
        if(warning.code === 'THIS_IS_UNDEFINED') { return; }

        console.warn(warning.message);
    },
    plugins: [
        nodeResolve({jsnext: true, module: true}),
        commonjs({
            include: 'node_modules/**',
            namedExports: {
                'node_modules/ng2-toastr/ng2-toastr': [ 'ToastModule' ]
            }
        }),
        uglify()
    ]
}
```

Now, the script generates the 'build.js' file and I can load it through the index.html file, but the component 'ng2-toastr' is not working (the component shows a 'toast' like message, appearing on one side of the screen and disappearing after a few seconds).

Did I miss something? Thanks in advance,